# Сформулировать просьбу: перевести на исполнение обязанностей увольняемого сотрудника?

Tags: грамотная-речь

название отдела и должности (просящего и увольняемого) одинаковые. Как литературно грамотно сформулировать, чтобы не получилось "масло масляное".

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу перевести меня на место увольняемого сотрудника и вменить мне выполнение его нынешних обязанностей.

/ Или *былых обязанностей* -- если тот сотрудник уже уволился. /